# Cant see keyframes in dope sheet

Tags: dopesheet

[image]

As you can see in the attached image, I add keyframes but i cannot see any change in the dopesheet. Just for info: I have 3 object selected, 2 are from another layer in the same scene and are group instances. Where as one of them is just made in the current layer of the current scene. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of tadd more information to the question. Also consider uploading the blend file for someone to inspect it. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I cant upload the blender file, its for work. Cant share that much sorry. I fixed it anyways. I just had to click on the little ghost icon to the right of "summary" at the bottom of the dope sheet.